# Reading a comma seperated data column, and using results to display rows from a different table

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Just a little bit stumped at the moment about best way to get the desired result i'm chasing.

So in my users table there is a column name "gshowcase" This field will have a series of numbers separated by a comma.

These numbers refer to the UID (auto increment) in my "games" table.

So if a user has the games ("4,5,9,15,25") it will display thoses rows on there profile from the games table.

Not sure if i have describe this very well lol

EDIT-----------------------------
Where am i going wrong???

```
 function getGrelationsList() {
    // The query to select the gamesid from the relations table
    $query = sprintf("SELECT `game` FROM `grelations` WHERE `user` = '%s'", $this->db->real_escape_string($this->id));

    // Run the query
    $result = $this->db->query($query);

    // The array to store the gameids the user plays
    $gamesplayed = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $gamesplayed[] = $row['game'];

    // Close the query
    $result->close();

    // Return the games info list (e.g: 13,22,19)
    return implode(',', $gamesplayed);
}


function getGshowcase() {
    // The query to select Games info based on gameids returned in previous function

    $query = sprintf("SELECT `idu`, `title`, `image`, `url`, `desc` FROM `games` WHERE `idu` =  $gamesplayed");

    // Run the query
    $result = $this->db->query($query);

    // The array to store the games info
    $gshowcase = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $gshowcase[] = $row['idu','title','image','url','desc'];
    }

    // Close the query
    $result->close();

    // Return the games info list (e.g: 13,22,19)
    return implode(',', $gshowcase);
}

function sidebarGames($type, $for) {
    global $LNG;

    $result = $this->Gshowcase;
    $title = $LNG['subshowcase'];
    $r = 'showcase';


    // If the select was made

    if($for == 0) {
        $i = 0;
        $output = '<div class="sidebar-container widget-'.$r.'"><div class="sidebar-content"><div class="sidebar-header"><a href="'.$this->url.'/'.((!empty($this->profile)) ? $this->profile : $this->username).'&r='.$r.'">'.$title.' <span class="sidebar-header-light">('.$result[1].')</span></a></div>';
        foreach($result[0] as $row) {
            if($i == 6) break; // Display only the last 6 Games
            // Add the elements to the array
            $output .= '<div class="sidebar-subscriptions"><div class="sidebar-title-container"><a href="'.$row['url'].'"><div class="sidebar-title-name">'.$row['title'].'</div></a></div><a href="'.$row1['url'].'"><img src="'.$this->url.'/thumb.php?src='.$row['image'].'&t=a&w=112&h=112" /></a></div>';
            $i++;
        }
        $output .= '</div></div>';
    } elseif($for == 1) {
        $output = '<strong><a href="'.$this->url.'/'.((!empty($this->profile)) ? $this->profile : $this->username).'&r='.$r.'">'.$result[1].' '.$LNG['people'].'</strong></a>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Regards
Rhys

Comment: That is bad table design. Can you change it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of including links to images that we can't see - can you please edit your question and add (simplified) examples of the data instead as tables? Links can die and we want our questions to stick around forever... plus there's a lot of link-baiting spam, and we want to discourage offsite links for that reason too.

Comment: Secondly - if you've had a go at it yourself, can you show us the code you came up with (even if it's broken) - that will help us get an idea of what you're trying to do. Use pseudo code if you need to.

Comment: Alright, Leave this question here for a bit, ill have an attempt at it then come back and edit post :) sorry first time using the site. Unaware of the way it operates.

Thankyou for taking the time to respond

Edit. I did have a go at it then scrapped it ,as thought i was going offtrack lol

Comment: @juergend the users one of the games table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema design you chosen can be improved to tackle your problem effectively. There must be `MANY-TO-MANY` relationship between userDB and gamesDB (assuming these are tables instead of dbs :P).

Using many-to-many approach you can you will have intermediate table say `user_games` for mapping which will have `userDB's primary key and gamesDB's primary key` as its own composite primary key.

Now as I am working on ORM in java. Using this kind of schema I can directly have `list of gamesDB` objects inside userDB instance. Else I can iterate over each row from user_games for the user and prepare object for each associated game and set this list of games into userDB's object.

And now convert this userDB's object in `JSON` using any open-source lib and return it to client. The returned json may be following format

```
{
  'userid' : 1,
  //other user info...
  games_list : [
     {
        'idu' : 1,
        'title': 'Counter strike...',
        //other info...
     },
     {
        'idu' : 2,
        'title': 'H1Z1',
        //other info...
     },
     //Other associated games
  ]
}
```

Now in `javascript` you can easy iterate over this json and render the view.

---

If it is not possible to change DB schema. you can still use this approach. But now you need to first make an `array` of game_ids by splitting `gshowcase` by comma and then iterate over each id and get the game row from db and prepare game object from this.

Comment: .Prob too late to change the DB schema, "If it is not possible to change DB schema. you can still use this approach. But now you need to first make an array of game_ids by splitting gshowcase by comma and then iterate over each id and get the game row from db and prepare game object from this" ^^ <-- This is exactly what i'm trying to achieve. Are you able to point me in the best direction of making an array by spliting the table result by comma. Thankyou for responding too

Comment: Going to run with the Many-to-many concept. Understand what you mean and seems alot cleaner

Comment: Cool.. Try to explore ORM framework in the language you are using. It will be bit tinetaking at first but will simplify code in long term.

Comment: Amit. I have been trying the work with the MANY-TO-MANY idea. I have edited original post, but cannot get it to work :/ Any suggestions??

Comment: I am little confused about the program. Could you please explain a bit where getGrelationsList() is called and I think you should use "SELECT `idu`, `title`, `image`, `url`, `desc` FROM `games` WHERE `idu` IN $gamesplayed" in function getGshowcase().